# comparing hashmap data

Tags: java, hashmap

I was wondering if it is possible to compare items in multiple hashMaps to each other:

```
HashMap<String,String> valueMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
HashMap<String,Integer> formulaMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

What I would basically like to do is something like:

```
if(the second string in valueMap is the same as the first string in formulaMap){
}
```

Is there a short way to achieve this or do I have to compare the strings before they are included into the hashMaps. My Integer at this stage of the program is required to take a **null** value. I can achieve my goals with a multi-dimensional array, but a solution like this would be more elegant and less time consuming.

Comment: there is no first or second in a `HashMap`. You need a `LinkedHashMap` for that.

Comment: First and second is not defined for a hashmap and could be a moving target.

Comment: you want to compare key, value or both?

Comment: Thanks never knew there was a **linkedHashMap**. I assume that I can add items to it in the same way I would add items from a list to a linked list?

Comment: I've tried the comparekey and comparevalue methods before, and I get a blank result when I printout my map. My code is very tricky, so It's possible I've made a mistake. Will try them again

Comment: @Digitalwolf The concept behind "linked" is based on a chain. Each element knows its predecesor and its succesor, plus the overal structure knows which element is the "head" and which one is the "tail" of the collection (a map is, in the end, a collection of entries).

Comment: Thanks, this actually also solves a problem that I'm going to have very soon on the ordering of my data. Thanks so much =D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using a `LinkedHashMap` you can have a map that respects the insertion order of different values. Everything you have to do is iterate over the `entrySet` of the map until you reach the position you're looking for.

Plus: If you also need ordering, you can have a look at the `TreeMap` which inserts elements in order based on a criteria defined by you (You can pass a `Comparator` as a parameter for the map).

This order will apply to the keys of the map tough, so if you need value ordering you're going to have to come up with a little more complex solution (as in sorting the entry set directly and adding the values to another map, for example).

Comment: would be better if you expand your answer with suggestion to compare `values()` of hasmap. e.g. hashMapA.values().equals(hashMapB.values())